# Android Studio App Builds but doesn't install or run for some flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-studio-arctic-fox

I'm having a really bizarre problem with an Android Studio project and I'm at a complete loss.

This project has its core `Flavor`, and then there are multiple re-branded versions of it that are assigned via their own `productFlavor` in `build.gradle`, for example:

```
productFlavors {
    mainBrand {
        applicationId('my.main.brand.app')
        buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_BRAND_STRING", "I am the main brand"
    }
    secondBrand {
        applicationId('my.second.brand.app')
        buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_BRAND_STRING", "I am the second brand"
    }
    thirdBrand {
        applicationId('my.third.brand.app')
        buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_BRAND_STRING", "I am the third brand"
    }
    fourthBrand {
        applicationId('my.fourth.brand.app')
        buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_BRAND_STRING", "I am the fourth brand"
    }
}
```

Each brand can have its own folder with its own resources, and the folder is named the same as the `Flavor` name. If a brand doesn't have its own folder, or a resource isn't included in its folder, then it just uses the required resource from the main folder.

This has all been working for over a year and I've not had any issues with it until very recently, when I was ready to do the final tests on the Debug versions for each brand before creating their signed APKS.  I had been working on changes to the second brand and then switching to the third brand to make sure everything was working, but when I came to test `mainBrand` I suddenly wasn't able to install it on to a physical device or an emulator.

After switching to the `mainBrand` `Flavor` and pressing the `Run` button, it builds successfully without any errors, but never opens on the device.  Eventually, after about 300 seconds, a message appears on the `Run` window saying `Timed out waiting for process (my.main.brand.app) to appear on *device-name*`

I get no errors reported in the build or logcat, it just doesn't even seem to try to install.

There are actually about 7 `Flavors` set up, although only 4 are used, but I checked through all of them and everything worked except `mainBrand` and `sixthBrand`.

Before taking the step to delete Android Studio, I committed and pushed my project via `git` and merged them in to my laptop instead.  On my laptop, `mainBrand` worked, as did most of the others, but `fourthBrand` and `fifthBrand` exhibited exactly the same problem that `mainBrand` was having on my main computer!

I spent hours testing on my laptop, making copies of "working" `Flavor`s and their associated files, and renaming them. Initially a direct copy with a new name like `secondBrandCopyTest` would work, and seemed to continue to work as I gradually changed all of the files and `gradle` settings back, but then stopped working once I put its `Flavor` name back to `secondBrand`.  It also didn't work with several other names, which I've never used before.  Eventually I noticed that all of my tests with short `Flavor` names were failing, and on my laptop I got all `Flavors` working by renaming them all to longer versions of their own names like `secondBrandLongerName`.  I refused to believe that this was legitimate fix, but I thought it would work in the mean time and I'd try and work out why this "fixed" it when I had more time.

I returned to my main computer and applied the same logic - renamed all `Flavor`s and associated folder names, and it still doesn't work!

Any ideas for how I can even start to find out what is causing this?  Other things I've tried:

- Clean and Rebuild
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Completely remove Android Studio and reinstall (had to be done manually as it didn't work through Control Panel)
- Rename the project
- Manually deleting all `build`, `gradle`, `idea` folders.
- Changing the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 28, 29 and 30
- Changing `gradle` version to 7
- Building the APK and installing it separately (also doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

That's because different flavors have different keystores.

So, you need to be careful. Android OS considers them different.